# Generating specific byte sequence in Simulink

Tags: matlab, byte, simulink, pack

I am trying to communicate with a camera in Simulink via the two blocks `tcp/ip` and `receive/send`.
Therefore I need to send the following specific 12 byte sequence (displayed in hex):

```
07:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:8c:01:00
```

I was trying to solve it with the simulink block "byte pack". I connected 12 constant-blocks with it and chose the decimal for each constant-block, that is corresponding to a byte of the 12 bytes, and changed the input data type to double. But it didnt work and I dont know what I've made wrong.

Any suggestions or other solutions to my problem?